# Is there an equivalent of the Google analytics custom variables "page" scope for Google analytics dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to upgrade a site's Google Analytics (GA) from the previous ga.js API to the newer analytics.js API.  I have an issue with the conversion of Custom Variables into Custom Dimensions.

Previously, custom variables had their scope set to "page".  However, when I try to create a custom dimension there is no "page" scope.  Is there a Dimension scope value equivalent to the "page" scope used in custom variables from the old api.

ga.js api custom variable scope can have one of these values:

- Visitor
- Session
- Page

In the new analytics.js api the scope value for a dimension can be:

- Product
- Hit
- Session
- User

Answer (score 0):

Hit level corresponds to page level, it is just a more generic term - each pageview is a hit, but not every hit is a pageview (you can append dimensions to events etc. wich are also hits). So simply sent a hit level dimension along with a pageview (i.e. in the configuration object of the pageview, not via a "set" call).